# Insertar datos en objeto WWSD a través de BC en GeneXus

Tags: genexus

Estoy queriendo agregar una `Reserva` a partir de un `Vehiculo`, sería entrar en la tabla de vehículos en su *patterns smart devices* y agregar un botón RESERVAR que pueda llamar a la tabla Reservas en su objeto *smart* y con el IdVehiculo ingresar los datos de la reserva.

Utilizo &BC enviándole como parámetro:

```
Composite
    &Vehiculos = &Vehiculos.VehiculosId
    WorkWithDevicesReservas.Reservas.Detail.Insert(&Vehiculos)
    Refresh
EndCmposite
```

Pero no me acepta GX y me dice que está mal la sintaxis. ¿Me podrían ayudar?

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te da? Ayudaría que pegues el mismo en la pregunta...

Answer (score 0):

La variable que le pasas al `.Insert()` tiene que ser del mismo tipo que el WWSD.

En tu ejemplo, si estás llamando al `WorkWithDevicesReservas`, deberías pasarle una variable basada en el `Business Component` `Reserva`.

Algo así:

```
composite
    &reserva.VehiculoId = &vehiculoId
    WorkWithDevicesReservas.Reservas.Detail.Insert(&reserva)
    Refresh
endcomposite
```